# Access Token not returned from Facebook API redirect in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, access-token

I have the following redirect in my Page_Load method of Default.aspx...

Response.Redirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:50049/home.aspx&response_type=token");

I didn't include my actual client_id, obviously, but it is correct in my code, and this redirect works fine (the login dialog box appears and the browser redirects to home.aspx when submitted, but it doesn't provide me with the needed access_token to do other Graph API calls with, etc.

The way I am trying to obtain the access_token is the Request.QueryString, which is empty with the response_type parameter of token (to return an access token) or code%20token (to return both the code and access token) as indicated in the SDK doc.  With the parameter omitted, the Request.QueryString appears to have the code value, which is the default.

Comment: i think accesstoken. is returned as URL fragment.  ie after the hash.?

Comment: My opinion is to use Facebook Javascript SDK, and that to avoid the server having to request access tokens all the time, and that also to save on bandwidth, ideally what you could do is authenticate the user using Javascript, get the token and send it back to the server to do graph api requests using that token.

In any case, Facebook doesn't return the access token right away, it returns a code then you'll have to request another URL with that code and the client_id to be able to get the access token